# Taxi or bus from Rabat to Marrakech

Tags: public-transport, taxis, morocco, marrakech, rabat

Three of us are going to go to Morocco about 20th February. I've read (on RomeToRio) that it is about 200 Dirhams by Grand Taxi from Rabat to Marrakech. Is this accurate for three passengers? Or would it be cheaper for three people to take the bus?

EDIT: I've edited Fez to Rabat, my mistake.

Comment: I have personally never been to Morocco but my understanding is that a “grand taxi” is actually a kind of minibus/shared taxi service as you can find in many developing countries, not a taxicab service. You're not hiring the car but paying for your seat so you can't divide the price by three.

Answer (score 2):

Edit (after the origin city was updated by OP):

Train fares can be found on the ONCF website, but can't be linked to. On [this page](http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx), there's a "Prix & Reservation" in the left column, where you can search for fares. Rabat to Marrakech is 120 Dirham.

Original:

That sounds rather low. Could it be the price per person, as opposed to the price per taxi? A train from Fez go Marrakech on [ONCF](http://www.oncf.ma/) costs 195 per person.

Comment: Ups, big mistake. I've ment from Rabat to Marrakech but I suppose it is similar. Here is the link: http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Rabat/Marrakesh So I've just divided the price between three persons. I've edited the question.

Comment: Could you send me an url of train you've found there? I can't  find anything when I choose Fes and Marrakech or Fes and Rabat. Thank you

Comment: Or better, I maybe found something but there is no price there. For example http://www.oncf.ma/Pages/ResultatsHoraire.aspx?depart=FES&arrivee=MARRAKECH&CodeRD=0093&CodeGD=00380&CodeRA=0093&CodeGA=00110&heure=0000&date=21/02/2016

Answer (score 1):

### Train from Rabat to Marrakech

[The Supratours website quotes 120 MAD](http://www.supratours.ma/horaires/gethoraire_prix) to get from Rabat, be it Ville or Agdal, to Marrakech by direct train, for a journey of approximately 5 hours:

[image: Supratours Rabat to Marrakech]

The quote is also confirmed by the [OCNF website (select departure and arrival stations to get a quote)](http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsNormaux.aspx):

[image: OCNF Rabat to Marrakech]

#### There Are No Buses Between Rabat and Marrakech

Moreover, [there seem to be no bus service between Rabat and Marrakech](http://www.oncf.ma/PrixEtReservation/Pages/BilletsAutocars.aspx) (since these two cities are linked by train):

[image: No Buses Rabat/Marrakech]

### Taxi from Rabat to Marrakech

IMHO you are unlikely to find a definitive valid quote online for a grand taxi service from Rabat to Marrakech. This is ever more true since taxi fares are often subject to (strong) haggling. Nevertheless [I found a website quoting 192 EUR for three passengers](https://www.taxismaroc.com/tarif-taxi-maroc-prix-navette-maroc):

[image: Taxi Rabat to Marrakech]

All the quoted prices are valid as of the 22nd of December 2015.